# Explode string with brackets and without brackets

Tags: php

I have values that look like this...

```
{X}{Y}{Z}{R}{R}
```

I have 2 questions, first question, how can I explode it so the resulting array looks like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => {X}
    [1] => {Y}
    [2] => {Z}
    [3] => {R}
    [4] => {R}
)
```

And the second question is, how can I explode it like this...

```
Array
(
    [0] => X
    [1] => Y
    [2] => Z
    [3] => R
    [4] => R
)
```

Comment: One method is to use a string splitting function and split on "}{", then chop "{" and "}" off the endpoints of the resulting array.

Comment: @icktoofay: It will never look that way.

Comment: @rotaercz: Fair enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is :

```
$str = "{X}{Y}{Z}{R}{R}" ;
preg_match_all("/\{([A-Z])\}/", $str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

[See Live DEMO](https://eval.in/45006)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {X}
            [1] => {Y}
            [2] => {Z}
            [3] => {R}
            [4] => {R}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => X
            [1] => Y
            [2] => Z
            [3] => R
            [4] => R
        )

)
```

---

### Explanation

This uses the regular expression `\{([A-Z])\}`. Bit-by-bit, it means:

- **`\{`** Match a literal `{`.
- **`(...)`** Match the content within normally, but capture whatever text it matched.

  - **`[A-Z]`** Match any character between `A` and `Z`.
- **`\}`** Match a literal `}`.

We use [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all) to find all instances of this pattern. Group 0 is the entire match (including the braces), and group 1 contains only the data captured using the parentheses.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on here? /\{([A-Z])\}/ The values can also be numbers such as {1/2}{1}{2}{3}, so I want to be sure it works correctly.

Comment: I see I can change [A-Z] to [0-Z] to support integers but how would it work for values like: {1/2}{R/G}?

Comment: @rotaercz: If you want to support slashes, digits, and uppercase alphabetic characters, you can use `[/0-9A-Z]`.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to the following and it works perfectly: preg_match_all("/\{([^}]*)\}/", $str,$matches);